# How to remove the double [[ for a 1D matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am working on a Deep Learning project (in Python), and I had a problem with my code. I get an output like this:

```
[[-0.00111287 -0.97692661 -0.9939433  -0.99474857]]
```

and I want to change that to this:

```
[-0.00111287 -0.97692661 -0.9939433  -0.99474857]
```

Can anyone help me with a simple function. I could not find any function that did the job.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `new_list = old_double_list[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a `numpy.ndarray`? You can flatten any array into 1D by doing `array.ravel()`. Additionally, you can reshape an array into any desired shape (compatible with the number of elements in the array) using `array.reshape`. `array.reshape(-1)` is the same as `array.ravel()`. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for more on reshaping arrays. Finally, you could also get `array_1d = array_2d[0]`, but I don't find this as clear in code because it seems to the reader like you are just selecting the first row of a 2D array. Doing `array_1d = array_2d.ravel()` makes it clear that you are keeping all elements, just flattening the array.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. It solved the problem for me. Wondering why I didn't come across this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = [[-0.00111287, -0.97692661, -0.9939433, -0.99474857]]
result = list(np.array(my_matrix).reshape(-1))
print(result)

# [-0.00111287, -0.97692661, -0.9939433, -0.99474857]
```

Comment: If you don't have a `numpy.ndarray` to start with and don't want one as output, it seems like a lot of overhead to go through `numpy` in the middle. For a list, you can just `array_1d = [element for row in array_2d for element in row]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not working with a numpy array, itertools provides a function called chain() that can be used to flatten a list:

```
from itertools import chain
array = list(chain(*matrix))
```